# printing all lines when multiple matching values in table perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have two tables: $conversion and $table. In my script I'm checking if there is a match between cols[5] from $conversion and cols[2] from $table, if this is the case I print out the value from another column in $conversion, namely the corresponding value in cols[1].

This is all working fine.

However some values in cols[5] from $conversion are the same. If this is the case I want to print off course everything from $conversion that matches. Now he prints only the corresponding value for the last match that he finds while going through the file. So when cols[5] from $conversion contains 4 times the same value, in the output only the corresponding value of the 4th match is printed. Any hint on how to solve this?

This is my script:

```
my %hash = ();
while (<$conversion>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split(/\t/);
    my $keyfield = $cols[5];
    my $keyfield2 = $cols[1];
    $hash{$keyfield} = $keyfield2;
}
seek $table,0,0;   #cursor resetting
while (<$table>) {
    my @cols = split(/\t/); 
    my $keyfield = $cols[2]; 
    if (exists($hash{$keyfield})) {
        print $output "$cols[0]", "\t", "$hash{$keyfield}", "\t", "$cols[1]\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Add input and expected output which will understand us more clearly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store a single `$col[1]`, store the whole array of them:

```
push @{ $hash{$keyfield} }, $keyfield2;
```

You'll need to dereference the array reference when printing:

```
print $output "$cols[0]","\t","@{ $hash{$keyfield} }","\t","$cols[1]\n";
```

If you want unique values, you can use a hash instead of an array.

Comment: Global symbol "$hash" requires explicit package name at script.pl line 30. Line 30 is the one with push in the beginning.

Comment: @user1987607: Copy'n'paste error? I used `$hash{`, which means the symbol is `%hash`, not `$hash`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my %hash = ();
    while(<$conversion>){
    chomp;
    my @cols = split(/\t/);
    my $keyfield = $cols[5];
    my $keyfield2 = $cols[1];

    push @$hash{$keyfield}, $keyfield2;
    # $hash{$keyfield} = $keyfield2;
}
seek $table,0,0; #cursor resetting
while(<$table>){
    my @cols = split(/\t/); 
    my $keyfield = $cols[2]; 
    if (exists($hash{$keyfield})){
        foreach(@$hash{$keyfield})
            print $output "$cols[0]","\t","$_","\t","$cols[1]\n";
}
}
```